# kill a system persistent process in android

Tags: android, process

Is there any way in android system to stop a system persistent process such as com.android.phone temporarily,  I tried (android.os.Process.killProcess) in a loop without success.

Thanks in advance,

Edit: 
Even with root privileges I am unable to achieve that

```
       tel= android.os.Process.PHONE_UID; 
       Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" ); 
       Process kil = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 tell");
```

Comment: `killProcess()` does not work at all to kill other processes, unless your app is running with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: whoops, Mark Murphy beat me to it. :)

Can't be done unless you have root access on the device.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int)

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows
>   us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will
>   still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able
>   to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's
>   packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;
>   packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's
>   processes.